# vue, Using javascript hook to achieve animation failure

Tags: javascript, animation, vue.js, hook

I wrote an animation component that works fine, but implements it using the class name as follows:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <transition name="bar">
            <slot></slot>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>

<style lang="stylus" scoped>
.bar-enter-active, .bar-leave-active{
    transition: all .3s;
}

.bar-leave-active{
    transform translateY(200px)
}

.bar-enter{
    transform translateY(200px)
}
</style>
```

But now I want to implement it through the javascript hook, because there are some parameters that need to be passed in from outside the component, such as: direction (from top to bottom, left to right, etc.), sliding distance, etc.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <transition
            v-on:before-enter="beforeEnter"
            v-on:enter="enter"
            v-on:leave="leave"
        >
            <slot></slot>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'animation',
    methods: {
        beforeEnter: function (el) {
            el.style.transform = 'translate-y(200px)'
        },
        enter: function (el, done) {
            el.style.transitionDuration = "3s"
            el.style.transitionProperty = "all"
            done()
        },
        leave: function (el, done) {
            el.style.transform = 'translate-y(200px)'
            // el.style.transition = 'all 3s'
            el.style.transitionDuration  = "3s"
            el.style.transitionProperty = "all"
            done()
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

I had difficulty at first, because I found that `el.style.transform = 'translate-y(200px)'` didn’t work at all.

I just want them to achieve the same effect, but where is the problem ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm not an expert, but don't you need to do something like el.target.style.whatever?

Comment: code looks fine, check if there is another transition with  `name="bar"`

Comment: @Helpinghand Thanks! The second code is that I forgot to delete it (`name="bar"`).

Comment: @git-e-up Thank you, I tried it, `el.target` will get undefined